# Get suggested invitees failed due to error code: 3

Tags: google-app-invites

I'm trying to run App Invites demo on a kitkat device but it returns

```
Get suggested invitees failed due to error code: 3
```

and soon after

```
Create invitations failed to error code: 3
```

What kind of error is it? Where i can find an error list?

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, this happens when the SHA-1 signature of your app is not compatible with the Android API key specified in the [Google Developer Console](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=appinvite)

If you don't care which app invites you, then you might want to consider removing app/signature restrictions. Otherwise, simply add them.

Comment: How can I do this ? Please help me.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106497/app-invites-using-firebase-not-working/40159638#40159638

Answer (score 0):

Log onto Firebase Console: https://console.firebase.google.com

You will need to click on the "Add Fingerprint" button and then add on your SHA1 key. You do not need to redownload your google-services.json, you just need to add the SHA1 key.

Try sending an app invite from your app. It will now work.

[image]